# Can share folder be bigger in size than the virtual hardisk of the guest os

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-server-2016

I have ubuntu operating system(guest) installed on windows server 2016(host) and i have shared a folder within them. My scenario is that shared folder can be up to 10TB and my virtual hard disk for the guest operating system is 60GB only. Does it affect the virtual hard disk of the ubuntu ? or it does not even occupy any physical space on the guest operating system ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Shared folders stored on Host VM and should not impact guest's file system. Simply said, if you add files to a shared folder inside the VM Host, only free space in Host system should decrease, while guest's system should stay at its current free space.